# Ruby - Converting a mixed string into an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I'm working on a problem where I am given a "coded" message in the form of a string, and have to return the decoded message. This requires me to split a string of mixed characters and numbers into an array. So for example, if I got a string like this:

```
"0h"
```

I want to split it into an array like this:

```
[0, "h"]
```

But when I use `.split` I get

```
["0", "h"]
```

The solutions I have found only take into account strings that are all numbers, but not mixed strings. Is there a way to convert the strings that are numbers into numbers while retaining the characters?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with a regular expression.

```
str = "0hh1ghi22d"

str.scan(/\d+|\D+/).map { |s| s =~ /\d+/ ? s.to_i : s }
  #=> [0, "hh", 1, "ghi", 22, "d"]
```

or

```
str.each_char.map { |s| s =~ /\d/ ? s.to_i : s }
  #=> [0, "h", "h", 1, "g", "h", "i", 2, 2, "d"]
```

depending on requirements.

Comment: `chars` as the first part also works if individual characters are desired.

Comment: @tadman, good suggestion, as the question is not clear on that. I did an edit.

Comment: You can avoid matching `\d+` twice by using capture groups: `str.scan(/(\D+)|(\d+)/).map { |s, d| s || d.to_i }` (note that I've changed the order of `\D+` and `\d+`)

Comment: @Stefan, that's lovely,but I don't understand why you needed to change the order of `\d+` and `\D+`. Readers, if you don't follow Stefan's code, note that `str.scan(/(\D+)|(\d+)/) #=> [[nil, "0"], ["hh", nil], [nil, "1"], ["ghi", nil], [nil, "22"], ["d", nil]]`.

Comment: Just to have the same order throughout the expression. The non-digits (`\D+`, `s` and `s`) are on the left-hand side, whereas the digits (`\d+`, `d` and `d.to_i`) are on the right-hand side.

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. Just so I know I understand what's happening since I'm really new at maps, it's passing each character to a block, seeing if the character is a number and if it is it converts it to an integer. Is that what /\d/ does? Just want to make sure I understand the logic of it. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: quartzcrusher, you got it! `r = /\d/` is a regular expression requiring a match on a single digit. We can write `"abc123" =~ r  #=> 3`. `3` equals the offset of the string where the match begins. Here we don't care about the offset, but since `3` is neither `false` nor `nil`, it evaluates logically as `true`. We also have `"abc" =~ r  #=> nil`, `"abc123"[r]  #=> "1"`, `"abc"[r]  #=> nil`, `"abc123".scan(r) => ["1", "2", "3"]`, and much more. `/\d+|\D+/` means match one or more digits (`\d+`) or (`|`) one or more non-digits (`\D+`).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have digits in the string end up as Fixnums in your array.

You can do this by adding a `.map` to your `split`:

```
... .map { |c| c =~ /\d/ ? c.to_i : c }
```